# How to install bootstrap in Laravel 5 using bower, gulp and elixir?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, laravel-5, gulp, bower, laravel-elixir

I added `bootstrap-sass-official` to my bower dependencies into `bower_components`.

I compiled and added bootstrap css files to `public` this way (in `gulpfile.js`):

```
var paths = {
    'bootstrap': 'bower_components/bootstrap-sass-official/assets/',
    'jquery':    'bower_components/jquery/dist/'
};


elixir(function(mix) {
    mix.sass('app.scss', null, {includePaths: [paths.bootstrap + 'stylesheets/']});
});
```

In `app.scss` there is a line `@import '_bootstrap';`. And css files are compiled and they work.

How can I add bootstrap fonts and scripts to the page?

Comment: Are you sure this question is even related to Elixir?

Comment: @OnorioCatenacci I meant Laravel Elixir: https://github.com/laravel/elixir

Comment: Always nice to drop kudos to the source of your solution for others to read more about - https://laravel-news.com/2014/10/setting-laravel-elixr-bootstrap/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out a solution:

```
mix.scripts(
    '*',
    'resources/assets/javascripts',
    'public/js/app.js'
);
mix.scripts(
    [
        paths.jquery + 'jquery.js',
        paths.bootstrap + 'javascripts/bootstrap.js'
    ],
    'public/js/dependencies.js',
    'bower_components'
);
mix.copy(paths.bootstrap + 'fonts/bootstrap/', "public/fonts/");
```

Answer (score 1):

My solution, I'm quite proud of.

**/gulpfile.js**

```
var elixir = require('laravel-elixir');

// Set your Bower target directory below.
var bowerDir = './vendor/bower_components';

// Helper function.
function bower(pkg, path) {
    return [bowerDir, pkg, path].join('/');
}

elixir(function (mix) {
    // Styles
    mix.sass('app.scss', null, {includePaths: [bowerDir]});

    // Fonts
    mix.copy(bower('bootstrap-sass', 'assets/fonts/**'), 'public/build/fonts');

    // Scripts
    mix.scripts([
        bower('jquery', 'dist/jquery.min.js'),
        bower('bootstrap-sass', 'assets/javascripts/bootstrap.min.js')
    ]);

    // Versioning
    mix.version([
        'css/app.css',
        'js/all.js'
    ]);
});
```

**/resources/assets/sass/app.scss**

```
@import "bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap";

body {
  font: 100% Helvetica, sans-serif;
  color: #333;
}
```

**Bonus tip for PhpStorm**

Set up `bowerDir` as Resource Root in PhpStorm. This way you will get rid off warnings.

[image: wrong]

[image: good]

[image: autocompletion]

Use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> to show up path autocompletion.

Comment: neat! those phpstorm warnings are really annoying